# CSS isn't properly applying the border-radius and also has problems with column extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

1. My corners don't get rounded (TOP-LEFT/RIGHT)
2. My column element doesn't extend to the bottom. (It goes up until the last child element)

I started coding 1 week ago, please be patient with me.

Screenshot of the problem!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUqhg.png)

HTML

```
                <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-6.4.2-web/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="weather">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="body">
            <img src="Pictures/weather-icon.png" class="image">
            <div class="temperature">34ºc</div>
            <div class="city">Anicuns, BR</div>
            <div class="info">Sunny</div>
                <div class="ablock">
                    <div class="aparticion">
                        <div class="ainfo">78</div>
                        <i class="fa fa-wind"></i>
                        <div class="cinfo">WindFlow</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bparticion">
                        <div class="ainfo">78</div>
                        <div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div>
                        <div class="cinfo">Preception</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cparticion">
                        <div class="ainfo">78</div>
                        <div class="fa fa-droplet"></div>
                        <div class="cinfo">Humidity</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="bblock"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    background-color: #90C9FF;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    margin: 0;
}

.weather {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}

.weather .header{
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body{ 
    width: 300px;
    height: 490px;
    background-color: #F4F9FF;
}

.weather .body .image {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #F4F9FF;
}

.weather .body .temperature {
    font-size: 40;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F4F9FF;
}

.weather .body .city {
   background-color: #F4F9FF; 
   font-size: 15;
   text-align: center;
}

.weather .body .info {
    background-color: #F4F9FF;
    font-size: 15;
    text-align: center;
}

.weather .body .ablock {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 105px;
}

/* Particion A */

.weather .body .ablock .aparticion {
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-left: 15%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.weather .body .ablock .aparticion .ainfo{
    color: #0094CB;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .aparticion .fa.fa-wind{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .aparticion .cinfo{
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Particion B */

.weather .body .ablock .bparticion {
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.weather .body .ablock .bparticion .ainfo{
    color: #0094CB;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .bparticion .fa.fa-grip-lines{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .bparticion .cinfo{
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Particion C */

.weather .body .ablock .cparticion {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .cparticion .ainfo{
    color: #0094CB;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .cparticion .fa.fa-droplet{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.weather .body .ablock .cparticion .cinfo{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.weather .body .bblock {
   background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 85px;
}

.weather .footer{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

1. I'm expecting to get my corners to be rounded.
2. I'm expecting to have my columns extended to the bottom.

Comment: Stop using such specific selectors. If your "ablock" elements are not descendents of a  "weather" and a "body" element, the rules won't apply. This is something you can check extremely easily with the browser DOM inspector tool.

Comment: They are descendents, i just didn't paste the whole code.

Comment: i'll edit the code, and paste it fully.

Comment: Your border-radius styles are working correctly. The problem is that those "particion" boxes inside "ablock" do *not* have rounded borders, so they "poke out" into the corners. If you give "ablock" the style `overflow: hidden;`, you will see the rounded corners. This is something, again, that you can see *extremely easily* with the browser DOM inspector tool.

Answer (score 0):

My corners don't get rounded (TOP-LEFT/RIGHT) - because your aparticion and cparticion has square corners and zero top porition. You have to add 8px and more top-margin to them or add rounded cornerns to them

My column element doesn't extend to the bottom. (It goes up until the last child element) - remove height: 105px; from .ablock